# Source a Python's file from another Python file

Tags: python

My question is maybe a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer.

How can I source a python file from another python file. Something like:

```
def fun_1 (arg):
   ...
   ...
   fun_2 (arg):
     ...
     ...

#### MAIN ####

Source the file that contains the function `fun_2`

fun_1('hello')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way is to turn the first file into a [module](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and `import` it into the second file:

```
$ cat file1.py
def fun():
   print('in fun1')

$ cat file2.py
import file1

file1.fun()
```

Comment: Also, you can do `from file1 import fun` and `fun()` if you only need one function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment. I did not understand though! When you write "from file1 import fun", do you give the whole path of file1? It doesn't work out for me.

Comment: @Remi.b: You can't import from an arbitrary path. The imported file has to be in the current directory or the path to its directory has to be in the `sys.path` list or added to it beforehand.

Comment: @Remi.b: You're welcome. You can also put the file in one of the directories already listed in `sys.path` or define the environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#environment-variables) with the path to the file in it.