# Reference a Python file in another Python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have two Python files, global.py and test_train.py, both sitting in the same folder. I am trying to allow test_train.py to access everything (functions, variables, etc. in global.py). I cannot get it to work. In the same folder is *init*.py. I have tried import global and have also referenced [Source a Python's file from another Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655688/source-a-pythons-file-from-another-python-file), but nothing seems to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your file (global.py) name, when you import global.py,
the module name global will conflict with python keyword **global**

```
import global  # global is keyword in python, you should avoid using this name
               # so it will occur error
import global_test  # this line is OK, if your .py name is global_test
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically `import global` should work. 
However, if it doesn't work, you should do a check to see if the import is happening successfully.
A `print` statement at the end of the `global.py` script should suffice to tell you so.

Otherwise, if the import is working, then you should try changing your code by encapsulating the entire contents of the `global.py` in a class, and then creating an object of that class in your `test_train.py` script to call its functions and attributes.

You can also make use of `getattr` function to call directly from `global.py`